# How to do string concatination in hive

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, concatenation, hiveql

I have 2 tables lets say table 1 as follows

[image]

and table 2 as follows

[image]

and the result i expected is

[image]

I tried concat_ws method in hive but the results are not as per expected and moreover when i use concat_ws method i can able to apply for only 1 field. Please let me know how to overcome or is there any solution available.

Answer (score 2):

Use `collect_set` to get an array of parts per (`name, function`), then use `concat_ws` to concatenate array using comma as delimiter:

```
select t.name1, t1.function, t2.parts, t2.body, t1.scope
from
(select name1, function,
        concat_ws(',',collect_set(scope)) as scope
   from table1
  group by name1, function
) t1
 inner join
(select name2, function,
        concat_ws(',',collect_set(parts)) as parts,
        concat_ws(',',collect_set(Body)) as Body
   from table2 t2 
  group by name2, function
)t2
 on t1.name1=t2.name2 and t1.function=t2.function
```

One more approach - without join, using UNION ALL+aggregation, this may be more performant:

```
select name, function,
       concat_ws(',',collect_set(parts)) as parts,
       concat_ws(',',collect_set(Body)) as Body,
       concat_ws(',',collect_set(scope)) as scope
from
(
select name1 as name, function, null as parts, null as Body, scope from table1
UNION ALL
select name2 as name, function, parts, Body, null as scope from table2
)s
group by name, function
```

Comment: I need the scope from table 1 to be added to end result.